# Find a parametric line equation that intersects two other lines at the point of closest approach

Tags: vectors, 3d

I have two parametric line equations for a 3D space, $A(t)$ and $B(t)$. Both of these lines have a "velocity" vector as a direction vector. Both equations actually represent a point moving through space at a specific speed, and the line represents its path through space. Each line equation has a different "speed".

So, I have these two line equations that actually represent moving points (think two mosquitos travelling in straight lines at different speeds).

I need to find a line equation that will "hit" both $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ (think bug spray, trying to hit the mosquitoes). This line also has a "velocity" (and thus "speed"). However, once the line intersects ("hits" is the term I used above) one of the other lines ($A(t)$ or $B(t)$), it will take some amount of time for it to intersect the other (as it is travelling at a constant speed, and not instantaneously). However, I need this line equation to travel the least possible distance between intersecting one line and then the other.

My problem arises in finding this line equation, specifically the direction vector. I need the third line to almost "predict" the future location of the lines - it hits one (say, $A(t)$) and then, because both $B(t)$ and the (not yet found) line would be travelling at different speeds, the (not yet found) line would need to be perfectly position to intersect $B(t)$.

So far, I've deduced that the third line will intersect $B(t)$ at $t = t_c - a$ and $A(t)$ at $t = t_c + b$ ($B(t)$ travels faster than $A(t)$, and thus the third line must intersect it first). $t_c$ is the $t$ value when $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ are closest together. $a$ and $b$ are some real values that represent seconds (the same unit as $t$).

I don't know where to go from here, or if I'm even on the right track. How could you find a line that intersects two other lines, with different velocities, while also minimising the distance the third line travels between intersecting the other lines?

I was hoping for some insight into the problem (specific values weren't provided for this reason - I don't need the full working, I just need some guidance to the solution). This is a fairly unique problem, as the lines I am dealing with actually represent a point moving through a 3D space.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: do you know about the $\mathbb R^3$'s cross product?

Comment: Is there a given velocity for the third line?

Comment: @user2271513 yes, there is

Comment: @janmarqz Yeah, I do. Could I use that here?

Comment: hint to start: given the two directions use their cross product to find a direction perpendicular to them ... I hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer I assume that the third line has a given speed $v$, and that the lines are not parallel. If the speed is just a maximum then this may not be the optimal solution. Let the first curve be given by
$$
\mathbf{l}_1 = t\mathbf{b}.
$$
Here we have just translated to remove one of the vectors. Suppose the second curve is given by
$$
\mathbf{l}_2 = \mathbf{a}' + t\mathbf{b}'
$$
Then if we leave at $\mathbf{l}_1$ at $t_1$ and arrive at $\mathbf{l}_2$ at $t_2$, we can calculate the vector between the points of intersection:
$$
\mathbf{d}(t_1, t_2) = \mathbf{a}' + t_2\mathbf{b}' - t_1\mathbf{b}.
$$
We know that
$$
\frac{\|\mathbf{d}\|}{t_2 - t_1} = v,
$$
and so
$$
t_2 = t_1 + \frac{\|\mathbf{d}\|}{v}. 
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{align}
\|\mathbf{d}\|^2 &= (\mathbf{a}' + t_2\mathbf{b}' - t_1\mathbf{b}).(\mathbf{a}' + t_2\mathbf{b}' - t_1\mathbf{b}) \\
&= \left(\mathbf{a}' + \frac{\|\mathbf d\|}{v}\mathbf{b}' + t_1(\mathbf{b}' - \mathbf{b})\right).\left(\mathbf{a}' + \frac{\|\mathbf d\|}{v}\mathbf{b}' + t_1(\mathbf{b}' - \mathbf{b})\right) 
\end{align}
$$
Which is a quadratic equation for $\|\mathbf d\|$ in terms of $t_1$ - if the roots are not real then this implies that we can't hit the other line when setting off from $\mathbf l_1$ at time $\mathbf t_1$.

We can rearrange the above equation to get an equation of the form
$$
\|d\|^2 - 2\beta(t_1)\|d\| + \gamma(t_1) = 0
$$
and so, from the quadratic formula
$$ 
 \|d\|(t_1) = \beta(t_1) \pm \sqrt{\beta(t_1)^2 - \gamma(t_1)} = f(t_1).
$$
where the appropriate root is chosen (this will depend on properties of the lines).

$\beta$ and $\gamma$ are smooth functions of $t$, so we can differentiate $f$ to find the critical points of the distance.

Comment: I've just come back to this (sorry for commenting so late after you posted this answer) but in your final equation, how is it possible to solve using the quadratic formula? Your final equation for $|d|^2$ is in terms of both $|d|$ and $t_1$... would this not make it implicit?

Comment: Yeah, the final expression is a quadratic equation in $|d|$ (as in of the form $a|d|^2+ b|d| + c$ after some rearranging, where the coefficients are functions of $t_1$) and so we can write $|d| = f(t_1)$ for some $f$ computed using the quadratic formula. Then pick $t_1$ to minimise $f$

Comment: but don't you end up with an equation with both $|d|$ and $t_1$? IN which case there are two unknowns - we don't know $|d|$ or $t_1$

Comment: Yeah exactly, but you can find the $t_1$ which minimises $|d|$ which is what you're after, in the same way that $y = x^2$ has two unknowns but $y$ is a minimum when $x$ is $0$

Comment: In rearranging, I've ended up with $|d|^2 = |a'|^2 + |\frac{|d|}{v}b'|^2 + |t_1 (b'-b)|^2 + 2(a'\cdot \frac{|d|}{v}b') + 2(a'\cdot t_1 (b'-b)) + 2(\frac{|d|}{v}b' \cdot t_1 (b'-b))$, which is implicit (I've tried to simplify it best I can). I cannot find a way to get $|d|$ on it's own on one side. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can use the quadratic formula, since this is a quadratic equation in $|d|$

Comment: But in order to use the quadratic equation I would need to get $a|d|^2 +b|d|^2 + c = 0$, and I can't seem to do that? Would you mind showing me what you mean? (you don't have to solve the whole thing, I just need to see what you mean)

Comment: sorry I should have been clearer - I've updated the answer

Comment: Ah yeah, I see now. Looks like my math was a bit funky before, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2):

Let $A(t)=tA_1+a_1$ and $B(t)=tB_1+b_1$ be your two lines.

Then $C=A_1\times B_1$ is a direction perpendicular to both directions $A_1,B_1$. Also this determine two planes $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ which contains directions $A_1$ and $B_1$ respectively.

With the vector $\vec{a_1b_1}$ we construct a triangle with vertices
$a_1,b_1$ and $E$. This last direction (also position) being the projection of the vector
$\vec{a_1b_1}$ on $\Pi_1$. Now we consider the Ansatz:
$$\vec{a_1b_1}=E+mC.$$

Pairing each side of this equation with $C$ we get
$\vec{a_1b_1}\cdot C=mC\cdot C$. We get this because $E$ and $C$ are perpendicular, so
$$m=\frac{\vec{a_1b_1}\cdot C}{C\cdot C},$$
and
$E=\vec{a_1b_1}-mC$ is got as a byproduct.

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

Comment: Thanks for you help! Quick question... how can I then use $E$ to find the third line? Using it as a direction vector makes a line that intersects $A(t)$, but not necessarily $B(t)$

Comment: $L(t)=tE+a_1$ is a line with direction $E$ that passes through $a_1$

Comment: yeah, but then how can I show that it passes through $B(t)$ as well?

Comment: it can't because it lies in the plane $\Pi_1$ which is a plane that doesn't intersect $\Pi_2$ since they are parallel planes, but the line $M(t)=t(b_1-a_1)+a_1$ can since $M(0)=a_1$ and $M(1)=b_1$.

Comment: Because all three lines need to have velocity, can you prove that the distance $M(t)$ travels between intersecting $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ is the smallest possible?

Comment: the picture is a little misleading, but the direction $E$ is parallel to the line $B(t)$ so by sliding $mC$ just to position $a_1$, a parallel line to $C$ will hit a point in $B(t)$ and which is at $-E$ from $b_1$. This point at the line $B(t)$ and $a_1$ are at the very same distance $\|mC\|$ as all points of $\Pi_1$ are from $\Pi_2$. Give me a little while to correct the picture.

Comment: Now is a better picture